# Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\Music\music_player.py - Shortcut.lnk", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'L' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.10

When I write `python music_player.py` in the windows command prompt the file runs successfully. [image]

**But** When I try the same with the `music_player.py` shortcut file `python "music_player.py - Shortcut.lnk"` it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Music\music_player.py - Shortcut.lnk", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'L' is not defined
```

[image]

**Also if I try to open a `.py` file with Python then it shows the same error.**

[image]

But now I uninstalled Python2 and also restarted my PC.

---

So my questions are:

1. If I write `python music_player.py` in Command Prompt it will run successfully, But if I try the same with the `music_player.py` shortcut file it shows me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Music\music_player.py - Shortcut.lnk", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'L' is not defined
```

2. If I right-click on any Python file and use `Open With Python` I get the same error.

**Note:**

1. This all happens since I installed python2.
2. All code is written in Python3
3. My code work in `vscode` and `Thonny`.
4. All Code Is Available On My Github [Repository](https://github.com/Sharimiqbal/music-player)(Too Many Lines Of Code).

Comment: can you provide some  code to help us figure it out this problem.

Comment: @LSeu As I say There Is no error in my code.

Comment: Ok my bad i may understand why your music_player is not running. Since you just double click on file from windows you need to create a batch file to give the system a python interpreter : go see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219045/windows-run-python-command-from-clickable-icon)

Comment: @LSeu This not my question

Comment: @LSeu  This is the GitHub link to my repository:https://github.com/Sharimiqbal/music-player

Comment: There you get the code

Comment: There is no actual problem here, you just misunderstand how to call a python script with parameters, the quotes are not necessary. Your current python call  is passing the .lnk file as a module, which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although whenever you double click to *run* that shortcut, it will redirect you to the original Python file, that shortcut file *itself* is not a module.

In windows command prompt you can use `type` command which displays the contents of a text file. (It is not a readable text file though)

[image]

As you see it has necessary information to redirect you when you double click on it. Then OS will execute the referenced file by the specified app which is `python.exe` in your case.

But Python cannot treat it like a regular Python module. It will inspect the content of that file which is showed by `type` command.

When you type, `python something`, it doesn't matter what file extension it has, interpreter reads the content, compile the content to create `pyc` file and then interpret that `pyc` file.

If you use `-m` option, Python can execute the original source file but **after that** it will give you the same error.As @martjin said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22250157/13944524):

> When you use the -m command-line flag, Python will **import** a module or
> package for you, **then** run it as a script. When you don't use the -m
> flag, the file you named is run as just a script.

So in the process of importing Python somehow resolves the source file's path and import the file. This is when the file is being executed(Modules are executed when they get imported). After that it will fail on running the actual shortcut file's content.

One solution is to execute it like this:

```sh
python -c "import os;os.startfile('p_file.py - Shortcut.lnk')"
```

So you are basically calling [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

> When operation is not
> specified or 'open', this acts like double-clicking the file in
> Windows Explorer, or giving the file name as an argument to the start
> command from the interactive command shell: the file is opened with
> whatever application (if any) its extension is associated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242615/discussion-between-sharim-iqbal-and-soroush-bakhtiary).